# Trouble using compareTo() with generics and a LinkedList and sort

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I'm trying to create a SortedList class that extends a LinkedList class, only difference between the two is the SortedList has a method to insert whatever its holding in order.

```
public class SortedList<T> extends LinkedList<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    // Class variables and constructor

    public void insert(T objectToAdd){
    Node<T> newNode = new Node<>(objectToAdd);
    Node<T> currentNode = head.getNext(); // Head node is a single sentinel node, so we always need to start comparing from its next.

    if (objectToAdd.compareTo(currentNode.getPayload()) == -1){
    // Insert and setup node links.

    } else if (... rest of here){

    }
}
```

Problem I'm having is using the compareTo gives this error:

http://puu.sh/vxKxv/c9ee91d54c.png

Here is the Node class.

```
public class Node<T>{

    // Class Variables
    private final T data;
    public int index;
    private Node<T> next;
    private Node<T> prev;

    public Node(T data) {
        this.payload = payload;
        this.next = null;
        this.prev = null;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<T> newNode) {
        this.next = newNode;
    }

    public void setPrev(Node<T> newNode) {
        this.prev = newNode;
    }

    public Node<T> getNext() {
        return this.next;
    }

    public Node<T> getPrev() {
        return this.prev;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

If you need me to post any of the other classes let me know.

Been stuck on this for awhile now, anyone able to help?

Comment: Tip: post error as string and not as image

Comment: Yea, edit the question to include the error *as text*. It shouldn't be rocket science.

Comment: You node class does not implement the `Comparable` interface and (in consequence) has no implementation of  `compareTo()`

Comment: Not just the node class, but `T` has to be comparable for `objectToAdd.compareTo` to work. Trouble is, the generics do not assert `T extends Comparable<T>`. Fix that, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T is not a concrete type, hence compiler knows only that it has objects defined in Object class. If somebody makes the SortedList it will not have compareTo method, hence it cannot work. You need to make sure that T will contain the compareTo method. The easiest way is

```
public class SortedList<T extends Comparable> extends LinkedList<T> implements Iterable<T> { ... }
```

Also in my opinion it is better to check

```
if (objectToAdd.compareTo(currentNode.getPayload()) < 0) { ... }
```

because it gives you the relation that objectToAdd < currentNode.getPayload() visually. Also Comparable interface gives no guarantee it will be -1. It says:

> @return  a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object
>            is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

Comment: That was it.

Thank you for your help!